# C# event listener using lock() still throws exceptions

Tags: c#, list, events, exception, xna

im making an xna game, the problem involves the following classes:
Game class - this class listens to the event listeners of the two classes below
Player class - this class launches a Fire() event, telling the game that the player fires a bullet
Bullet class - this class launches a SelfDestruct() event(after a certain traveled distance), telling the game that the instance has to be removed
The game class has a list of bullets, in the update method it does a foreach on this list
The event listener for Fire() adds a new bullet to the bullet list
The event listener for SelfDestruct() removes the sender from the list(by casting to bullet)

both events, as well as the update method locks the list for thread safety.
but it still throws an exception, telling that the list was modified during the foreach.

how do i solve this; since i do lock on the list.. but that doesnt work:

```
Update:
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    player.Update(GameTime gameTime);//can throw fire event
    lock(Bullets)//Lock the list for thread safett
    {
        foreach(Bullet b in Bullets)//Throws exception when bullet is added/removed
            b.Update(gameTime);//can throw selfdestruct event
    }
}

Fire listener:
void listen_fire(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Player p = (Player)sender;/used to get coordinates and rotation stored in the player
    lock(Bullets)
    {
        Bullets.Add(new Bullet(p.Position,p.Rotation));
    }
}

Self destruct listener:
void listen_selfdestruct(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(Bullets)
    {
        Bullets.Remove((Bullet)sender);
    }
}
```

I figured that this solution may fail because the event is thrown inside a thread that has the list locked by itself already

any solutions are welcome, thanks for reading my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection used in foreach is immutable. This is very much by design.

As it says on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

> The foreach statement is used to
>   iterate through the collection to get
>   the information that you want, but can
>   not be used to add or remove items
>   from the source collection to avoid
>   unpredictable side effects. **If you
>   need to add or remove items from the
>   source collection, use a for loop.**

for example this code will throw exception:

```
     List<string> lst = new List<string>();

     lst.Add("aaa");
     lst.Add("bbb");

     foreach (string curr in lst)
     {
        if (curr.Equals("aaa"))
        {
           lst.Remove(curr);
        }
     }
```

so i do this so i won't remove from the list while iterating on it:

```
     List<string> lst = new List<string>();

     lst.Add("aaa");
     lst.Add("bbb");
     List<string> lstToDel = new List<string>();

     foreach (string curr in lst)
     {
        if (curr.Equals("aaa"))
        {
           lstToDel.Add(curr);
        }
     }

     foreach (string currToDel in lstToDel)
     {
        lst.Remove(currToDel);
     }
```

now i don't know what items are in your `Bullets` but you can't update or remove them while in `foreach` statement

Comment: Thanks, i gave it some more thought, and only the events that add or remove items from the list will cause problems, so ill give the entities some properties that are checked after the update call(still in the foreach loop) to add the items to be removed/added onto seperate lists, and then enumerate those

Answer (score 0):

Additional `lock` statements on the same thread are ignored when already elevated to that `lock` for the thread. Your `foreach` initially locks the code for that thread, blocking all other threads, but the code could trigger an event (that isn't asynchronous) which also locks... But since the event would be on the same thread as the foreach, the code can enter the lock block in the event and you're trying to remove from a list that you're enumerating over as if you never locked at all.

The reason for this design is that one thread can do one thing at a time... Therefore re-entering a lock is OK if the thread already had the lock, because it can't be in both places at once... Thus the risk of thread safety issues does not exist for the single thread that currently has access to the lock - it can't race against itself in the same way that single threaded apps are thread safe.

To avoid this, consider using a thread safe collection, or delegating work to a worker thread/task.